# How to create “Publishing Image” site column programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

How can I create site column with "Publishing Image" content type programmatically in FeatureActivated method?

I need to add this site column to the List

Answer (score 1):

All this content Types located in Microsoft.Sharepoint.Publishing. So I have needed to reference this lib. And add this code.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (var rootWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
    {
        if (rootWeb == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        const string testSiteColumn = "TestSiteColumn";
        if (!rootWeb.Fields.ContainsField(testSiteColumn))
        {
            var newImageField = new ImageField(rootWeb.Fields, "Image", testSiteColumn)
                {
                    Group = "Test",
                    StaticName = "Test",
                    Title = "Test",
                    RichText = true,
                    RichTextMode = SPRichTextMode.FullHtml
                };
            rootWeb.Fields.Add(newImageField);
        }
    }
}
```

This ContentType doesn`t located in SPFieldType, so I have needed to hardcode type in new ImageField as "Image".

Works fine.